# Set size of JPanel, when there are no components in it

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, preferredsize

I have a custom JPanel. The only thing that is in it, is a drawing of a rectangle, using the `drawRect` method of the `Graphics` object. The JPanel is always in a very specific square size, refuses to get any bigger or smaller. Tried overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method, didn't work.

Tried setting different layout managers for this custom JPanel, and also tried every layout manager for the JPanel that hosts this JPanel. Still, the size of the custom JPanel stays the same.

As I said, the custom JPanel has no components in it, only a drawing of a rectangle.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried JPanel's `setSize` method?

Comment: try like this jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));  ??

Comment: The size depends on the layout manager used. (Place it in a GridLayout, and it *will* take the same size as the rest of the components). So it's not really possible to know what is the issue without knowing more about the rest of the layout.

Comment: Are you trying to make the rectangle/panel stretch with the resizing of the frame?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve:

- As far as your containing panel, you need to know which layout managers respect preferred sizes and which ones don't

  ```
                            Grid     Flow     Border    Box   GridBag
  Respect PreferredSize      NO       YES      NO       YES     YES
  ```
- That being said, if you wrap the painted `JPanel` in a `JPanel` with one of the *"NOs"*, the painted `JPanel` shoud stretch with the resizing of the frame.
- Also if you want the drawn rectangle to stretch along with its `JPanel`, then you need to remember to draw the rectangle with `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` of the `JPanel` and not use hard coded values.

Here is an example using `BorderLayout` as the containing panel's layout, and making use of `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` when performing the painting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StretchRect {

    public StretchRect() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new RectanglePanel());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class RectanglePanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.fillRect( (int)(getWidth() * 0.1), (int)(getHeight() * 0.1), 
                        (int)(getWidth() * 0.8), (int)(getHeight() * 0.8) );
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 200);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new StretchRect();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: More on overriding [`getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).