# Java Jpanel Zoom Button (netbeans 7.4 Gui buiilder)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I have a paint component where I draw some shapes but the problem my shapes exceed jPanel Size . because of that I search a solution of zoom jpanel. I don't know if this possible could someone help me I use net beans gui builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the shapes to size according to your `JPanel`, make use of the `JPanel`'s `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` e.g.

```
int x = (int)(getWidth() * 0.1);
int y = (int)(getHeight() * 0.1);
int width = (int)(getWidth() * 0.8);
int height = (int)(getheight() * 0.8):
g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
```

See a full running example [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22167425/2587435)

You can see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22214485/2587435) how to customize initialization code for your `JPanel` in GUI Builder

Answer (score 0):

Add your JPanel to a JScrollPane and add the JScrollPane to the container you were originally adding your JPanel to. Make sure to setPreferredSize to a size large enough to see all of your drawings whenever you draw a new shape or however you are doing your graphics.

Comment: Can you please explain further , I have my jpanel in a frame