# Netbean Java Swing, JPanel/Jlabel Cant cover whole Frame

Tags: java, swing, layout, netbeans, gui-builder

I want to make my `JLabel` cover the whole frame but when i do so it wont cover the text field and ok button. how do i make my `JLabel` to cover whole frame content.

[image]

P/s I want to make this `jlabel` as a background so i can put my icon in `jlabel` as background picture.

Comment: Set the layout manager of the `JLabel` add the other components to it...except the form editor won't let, you'll need to do it by hand...

Comment: im sorry for i am new to netbean and java, but where can i set the layout manager. thank MadProgrammer

Comment: What you're trying to do is not easily achieved in the form editor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I would do. Use a `JPanel` for the background and throw in some custom paint code.

1. Drag a `JPanel` to the form and expand that to cover the whole frame, to be the background.
2. Right click on the `JPanel` and select **Customize Code** from the context menu. You will see the following dialog. You can now edit the code.

   [image]
3. Make sure to select **custom creation** from the drop down and type this

   ```
   jPanel1 = new JPanel() {
       BufferedImage img;
       {
           try {
               img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow5.png"));
           } catch (IOException ex) {  ex.printStackTrace(); }
       }

       @Override
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);
           g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);

       }
   };
   ```
4. You probably will have to resolve imports. Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
5. Also you will have to change the path of the image to your path.

Here's my file structure

[image]

And here's the result

[image]

Comment: +1 and i vote your answer as my believe is getting things done by code instead of depending on platform editor is much beneficial to us for learning development.

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, i have find the answer [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOLJQ6lsFGE). from the tutorial, when we are trying to make Jpanel and Jlabel to cover our whole Jframe we had to:

1) Right click at Jframe.
2) Chose Set Layout
3) Find and click Null Layout
4) Then you can edit your Jlabel to cover whole frame as i do below. thank for those who help.

[image]

p/s : i know thank is discourage in stack overflow but it hard to hold myself to do so. thanks again.