# java swing jpanel display when clicking a button

Tags: java, swing

i'm new to swing. i've created a jpanel form using the swing palette design. It has jlabels, jtextfields and a jbutton. when the button is clicked, the data entered in the jtextfields is inserted in the database through the model.

i don't want the the jpanel to be always displayed so i would like to add another button that displays this jpanel form when i click on it. is it possible to perform this using the palette design knowing that the source code is locked in the initComponent private function, or do i have to re-code all the components and layout myself?

thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, but you'll to your hand dirty and write some code

Comment: @MadProgrammer Agreed, the Swing GUI creator (at least the one from NetBeans) always generates terrifying code, so I would support getting to the manual task instead!

Answer (score 1):

> "knowing that the source code is locked in the initComponent private function"

You can edit the auto-generated source code, as see [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22214485/2587435).

> "that displays this jpanel form when i click on it. is it possible to perform this using the palette design"

Sounds like you want to swap views. You can do that using `CardLayout` and yes, it can be done from the design view. You can see more at [How to Use CardLayout with Netbeans GUI Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898439/2587435)